# Is it necessary that we should have ADSL connection to access internet(network) through Android Emulator?

Tags: android

What are the settings required to access network for those who dont have ADSL connection?
Thanks...

Comment: Any internet connection should work with the emulator. It doesn't have to be ADSL. Do you have any internet connection? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I have Airtel's Internet connection & I am using MSWindowsXP Professional ver.2002,service pack-2.

Comment: Do you have to connect through a proxy to the internet?

Comment: I am trying to run XMPPClient(Gtalk client) App from my office but its not get connected but when I tried same app from my home system where I have ADSL connection there its working whats the reason ?

office system has a open connection(no proxy & firewall)

Answer (score 1):

If your network connection goes through a proxy to get out to the internet, you will need to set the proxy for the android emulator:

If using eclipse on windows,do the following:

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Launch -> Default Emulator Options

-http-proxy="http://w.x.y.z:8080"

Answer (score 0):

If your Computer has an internet connection your Emulator should also have an internet connection by default. It does not matter what kind of internet connection you have.